# Searching for a bound on a Mobius functions defined on $B(0,r)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb C$ such that $|\alpha|  \in (0,1)$. Prove that if $z\in \mathbb C$ is such that $|z| \le r < 1$ then :

$$ \frac{\alpha+|\alpha| z}{\alpha(1-\overline{\alpha} z)}\le \frac{1+r}{1-r} $$

I tried to use the Maximum Modulus Principle. Let $z\in \partial B(0,r) $ i.e $z=re^{i\theta}$ for some $\theta \in \mathbb R$. It's enough to looking for the maximum of:

$$ \frac{|\alpha+|\alpha| re^{i\theta}|}{|\alpha(1-\overline{\alpha} re^{i\theta})|}= \frac{|1+\frac{|\alpha|}{\alpha} re^{i\theta}|}{|1-\overline{\alpha} re^{i\theta}|}$$

I don't know how to proceed :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not require anything other than the triangle inequality. Estimate the numerator from above: 
$$
|\alpha+|\alpha| z|\le |\alpha|(1+r)
$$
and the denominator from below: 
$$
|\alpha(1-\overline{\alpha} z)| \ge |\alpha|(1-|\alpha|r) \ge |\alpha|(1-r)
$$